# Как заблокировать ссылки в меню, где есть подменю?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

```
<ul id="mega-1" class="first_level mega-menu">                
    <li class="item_menu"><a href="/rus/" class="f_level_link">111111</a>    
        <ul class="second_level">                             
            <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="/rus/new/">2222</a></li>
            <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="/rus/new/">2222</a></li>
        </ul>                                
    </li> 
    <li class="item_menu"><a href="/rus/" class="f_level_link">111111</a>    
        <ul class="second_level" >                             
            <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="/rus/new/">2222</a></li>
            <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="/rus/new/">2222</a></li>
        </ul>                                
    </li> 
    <li class="item_menu"><a href="/rus/" class="f_level_link">33333</a></li>     
</ul>​
```

Как заблокировать ссылки в меню  (111111), где есть подменю (2222)?  А в меню (333), должен выполниться переход. Есть ньюанс подменю всплывает по ховеру на juery. пробывал через false то ссылки тогда работают как надо( не переходят на другую страницу) но ховер эффект больше на работает. Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это в продолжение [предыдущего вопроса](http://tinyurl.com/96do3xu). Жаль вы удалили вариант на jsFiddle. Из-за этого и мой ответ "уплыл". Ещё раз выложите там примерчик? попробуем решить задачку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.mega-menu li').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('ul').length){
        $(this).find('a').eq(0).click(function(){
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Comment: В этом случае, за блокируются все ссылки, а мне нужно только те у которых есть подменю

Comment: Смотрите в сторону **stopPropagation()** и **stopImmediatePropagation()**

Comment: @Hancock_888, используйте для тех ссылок, где есть подменю. Или вы генерируете их динамически?

Comment: Да, через шаблон. (динамическая подгрузка)

Comment: В шаблоне в любом случае формируете вид ссылки - добавьте элементам, которые являются категориями, этот аттрибут. И всё:)